# Merging attributes by location in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile, merge

I am a newbie on PostGIS and I want to transfer an attribute or even a symbology from a layer to another. For example, I have a file with points that each country has a point at the center, I want to transfer the symbology to the country borders' polygon shape file to get a better visualization.

How can I merge attributes or transfer symbology?

Answer (score 2):

**symbology:**
You cannot directly transfer symbology from a point to a polygon.

**merging attributes:**
If you give more detail on your layers/tables, you will likely get more specific answers. Hopefully this gets you started if you are using SQL. Assuming you have a column in the polygon table with the correct data type for receiving the attributes from the point and there is a single point in each polygon:

```
UPDATE polygon
  SET polygon_data = point.point_data
  FROM point
  WHERE (SELECT ST_Contains(polygon.geom, point.geom)) = TRUE;
```

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Next time I'll be more specific.